# How to find different data in SQL Server table and equivalent table in Oracle?

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle, triggers, linked-server

There is a SQL Server tables which has equivalent tables in Oracle. They connect via a linked server and when a new record is inserted ,updated or deleted into/from SQL Server tables, the Oracle tables will be updated using different triggers.

If SQL Server triggers were disabled the Oracle tables would not updated as well. Thus different data rows are generated in SQL Server and Oracle.

How can we find these different data? Is this any way to check if triggers are enabled or not?

Comment: You should ask it on serverfault.

Comment: You can monitor somehow the triggers status, here's an example from mykong : https://mkyong.com/oracle/oracle-plsql-check-the-trigger-status/
Regarding comparing data from 2 different database servers, I suggest either to copy both to one server (either sqlserver or oracle) and comparing both with minus, or dumping both tables and using a third party tool to find diffs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's in "A" and not in "B" can be found using the `MINUS` set operator. For example, if there's a common `ID` column in both tables, you'd

```
select id from ms_sql_server_table
minus
select id from oracle_table
```

Apply the "linked server" syntax to it; in Oracle, that would be a database link, I presume.

---

I don't know how to check whether triggers are enabled in MS SQL Server; I don't use that database.